# Does Google have FB_Exchange_Token like functionality for their client side access tokens

Tags: oauth-2.0

The Facebook OAuth 2.0 implementation allows you to convert a client side short lived access token into a long lived token using the FB_Exchange_Token grant_type i.e.

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={YOUR_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret={YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET}&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token={SHORT_LIVED_ACCESS_TOKEN}

My question is does Google's version of OAuth 2.0 have a similar mechanism allowing me to get the short lived token via the client side flow, pass this token off to server and have the server convert that token so we can store the refresh token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Google doesn't have that functionality.  You'll need to use the server-side flow.

Can you give more info on the use case (in comments below?)

Comment: That's what I kinda figured but I just wanted to post this out there just to double check. The use case is that a user would add their Google account to their site account using the popup instead of the full server side redirect but then be able to get data and possibly post to history (once that's out) through other channels without having to log in every time. I will just have to use the server side flow thanks.